# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 while installing XGBoost on Mac

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, xgboost

I installed `xgboost` while running anaconda version python 2.7 successfully. However when I downloaded Anaconda version python 3 and try to install XGBoost I keep getting the error message:

When I use this code in terminal :

```
pip install xgboost
```

I get :

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/52/wgzpv6997ls_75gm5km3vqzw0000gn/T/pip-build-3wk9f1z7/xgboost/
```

I would like to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following commands for MacOSX:

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost
cd xgboost; cp make/minimum.mk ./config.mk; make -j4
```